# System 7.5 install fails (mac IIsi)

Tags: operating-system, mac-os-classic

I have been restoring a rather iconic (and temperamental!) Mac IIsi.

I have trouble installing System 7.5 on an IBM drive with Apple firmware that OS 7.0 installed just fine on. I am puzzled by the error messages (no detail, just failed, insert disk one, "system was left untouched").

The first issue was caused by a system folder being present on the target drive, albeit in the trash bin (failure on disk 4). Now I am hitting this unhelpful error on Disk 7 (the last).

Disks check out ok and were verified on the same machine/drive.

Tried installing on another hard disk, hit same error, also on Disk 7 (this other disk has an OS on it, but upgrade was progressing smoothly in that case).

Any suggestions? I am thinking of making a new disk 7, just in case, but I don't think that's the issue here. Is there some kind of software lock or protection that System 7 would honor that I need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one had a simple answer in the end. Disk 7 was not imaged correctly it turns out, even if it opened correctly when mounted. Making a new disk 7 resolved the issue altogether, so it was a read error that interrupted the install.

Sheesh Apple, an error message saying something ("because..") would have been nice.